# ActiveRecord query to compare a time interval

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How to do something like this using ActiveRecord?

```
Reservation.where("start..finish < 1 hour")
```

**start** and **finish** are time records:

```
2.2.1 :009 > Reservation.last.start.class
  Reservation Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations"  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Reservation Load (1.1ms)  SELECT  "reservations".* FROM "reservations"  ORDER BY "reservations"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Postgres you can use one of it's many [time and date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html)

```
Reservation.where("(finish - interval '1 hour') < start")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@reservationsWithinInterval1 = Reservation.where('startdate >= ? AND startdate < ? , @reservation.startdate, @reservation.enddate)

@reservationsWithinInterval2 = Reservation.where('enddate >= ? AND enddate < ?, @reservation.startdate, @reservation.enddate)
```

Then check if

```
if @reservationsWithinInterval1.count > 0 || @reservationsWithinInterval2.count>0
flash[:notice] = 'Select different time. Car already reserved in this time'
```